# Compiling the file with a main function to a specific file name instead of "a.out"

Tags: c++11, makefile

I have multiple files that `main.cpp` depends on. My `main.cpp` file contains `int main() {...}` in it. Currently, my command to compile `main.cpp` looks like so:

`g++ main.cpp src_file1.cpp src_file1.cpp header.h ...`

This generates `a.out`. I do not want this file to be named `a.out`. I want to control the main executable's file name. I tried using this command to do so:

`g++ main.cpp src_file1.cpp src_file1.cpp header.h ... -o main.out`

However, when I run this, I get the error:

`error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files`

I understand why this is happening, but I do not know how to fix it. Of course I still want g++ to compile my headers and other c++ files, but I would like the main file, `main.cpp` to be compiled as `main.out` instead of `a.out`. How can I do this?

Relevant makefile code (if you want):

```
SRC = block.cpp list.cpp blocker.cpp hasher.cpp header.h
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
CC = g++
STD = -std=c++11
ARGON = argon2/libargon2.a
TARGET = main.out

main: main.cpp $(SRC) argon2/argon2.h
  $(CC) main.cpp $(SRC) $(ARGON) $(CFLAGS) $(STD) $(TARGET)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass header files to the compiler as if they were source files. Try this:

```
SRC = block.cpp list.cpp blocker.cpp hasher.cpp
ARGON = argon2/libargon2.a
TARGET = main.out

main: main.cpp $(SRC) argon2/argon2.h header.h
    $(CC) main.cpp $(SRC) $(ARGON) $(CFLAGS) $(STD) -o $(TARGET)
```

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: @MattX: Great. Now that it works, I suggest you change the target from `main` to `main.out`, and the last part of the command from `-o $(TARGET)` to `-o $@`.

Comment: I am guessing that the $@ refers to the name of the target?

Comment: @MattX: [exactly](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).

Comment: So instead of making with `make main` I should make with `make main.out`

Comment: @MattX: You're getting into a space where you have many options.